# access remix addresses within contact

Tags: solidity, remix, ganache

I want to write tests for my simple solidity contract and one of the tests I have is to pass an address dynamically from remix or ganache-cli. Is there a way to access all other addresses from remix in a contract function?

[image]

Comment: It is not possible for a contract to have access outside the EVM. So accessing the accounts in your node is not possible.